# Select2 with XML

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-select2

We are trying to use xml with select2 provided by ivaynberg at http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2.

We are using the following code to fetch xml data

```
$('#selectbox').select2({
minimumInputLength: 1,
ajax: {
    url: 'test.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  data: function (term, page) {
    return {
      q: term
    };
  },
  results: function (data, page) {
      return { results: data.CATALOG };
  }
}});
```

The following is the XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>Bob Dylan</text>
</CD>
<CD>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>Bonnie Tyler</text>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

I dont know what is the mistake, the the Select2 does not load any data.

Someone please help us.

Comment: wrap up the entire code with `.ready()` function.

Comment: its already wrapped .ready() function, but does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a `results` function for the ajax options that returns an array of objects where each object has `id` and `text` properties.

The following is one way that works. It wraps the returned XML with a jQuery object and then uses jQuery methods to process the XML. You could also use native DOM methods to work with the XML.

```
$('#selectbox').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        url: 'test.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: function(term, page) { return { q: term }; },
        results: function(data) {
            return {
                results: $(data).children('CATALOG').children('CD').map(function() {
                    var $cd = $(this);
                    return {
                        id: $cd.children('id').text(),
                        text: $cd.children('text').text()
                    };
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1vq0ehL/1/)

Note: You will want each item to have a unique `id` value though. In your example XML, the two `<cd>` elements both have the value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some thing should  be follow :

First , your selectbox control should be a div

second , when you use ajax option , you should implements formatResult option and formatSelection option

The following is my code :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#userbox').select2({
              minimumInputLength: 1,
              ajax: {
                  url: 'test.xml',
                  dataType: 'xml',
                  data: function (term, page) {
                      return {
                          q: term
                      };
                  },
                  results: function (data, page) {
                      return { results:$(data).find("text") };
                  }
              },
              formatResult: movieFormatResult,
              formatSelection: movieFormatSelection
          });
      });

      function movieFormatResult(item,container,query) {

          if ($(item).text().indexOf(query.term) > -1) {
              return item;
          } 

      }


      function movieFormatSelection(item) {
          return $(item).text();
      }



 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
 <div id="userbox" style="width:300px"></div>
</div>
</form>
```